# Dellocation of ViewController Containing Background Thread

Tags: grand-central-dispatch

If an a UIViewController runs a background thread operation like the one shown below and is deallocated prior to compeletion (lets say it is popped from a UINavigationController), does the background thread stop? What is a good way to ensure that the background thread completes?
My concern is that if the user enters a value to field and the database is not updated prior to deallocation of the view controller, the database will not be updated.

```
    // Doing something on the main thread

dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    // Perform long running process

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Update the UI

    });
}); 

// Continue doing other stuff on the 
// main thread while process is running.
```

Comment: Through experimentation I determined that the background thread does complete after an object has been deallocated. My question is, why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the background thread will not stop.

This is because GCD will retain the block until the block completes. Your view controller becomes irrelevant as soon as you dispatch your block.

Also, if you have references to any variables, either view controller itself or local to the scope of method where the block was defined, those will be retained as well.

So there is a possibility that your view controller will not be deallocated even when it is no longer in the navigation stack.